# How can I disable Ctrl+Shift+W on Chrome for Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I just accidentally pressed Ctrl+Shift+W again and lost some work. I like using CTRL+W for individual windows, but I never want to close everything.  Is there a way to disable this on Chrome?

Comment: It's a shame hotkeys **still** cannot be disabled/altered. I would like to use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Q` in [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/), but that closes my Chrome :(

Comment: This is not a Windows-specific issue. It is a general browser issue and these browsers (Chrome and Firefox) both use these same hot-key combos in Ubuntu linux as well. AHK doesn't support other OSes, but I wonder if there are solutions that could work for those OS as well.

Comment: For MacOS the chrome installation has an option "Warn before quitting" in the Chrome menu. It's saved me many times over.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/q/704779/656580) you can find more options even without using AutoHotkey. I really like [this approach](https://superuser.com/a/1097584/656580).

Comment: This is a good question! I often use the middle of a pinky to press ctrl and another finger to press w to close individual tabs. It is so easy for the pinky to sometimes also press the large shift key right above ctrl. I don't want to have to use autohotkey though to remedy this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com/) to intercept the keyboard shortcut:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Regex

#IfWinActive, (- Google Chrome)$
    ^+w::
        ;do nothing
        return

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: This example did not work for me with AutoHotKey v1.1.09.02. After some tweaking I got this working: #IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
^w::Return
#IfWinActive

Answer (score 23):

The answer by iglvzx doesn't work for newer versions of [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (AHK). **Here is how you can do it with newer AHK versions:**

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Regex

#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    ^+w::
        ;do nothing
        return
    ^+q::
        ;do nothing
        return

#IfWinActive
```

This also prevents **Ctrl+Shift+Q** from quitting all of Chrome.

Comment: (to send ctrl W just remove the `+`)

Comment: This should be the default answer. This also works with Firefox Quantum if you change the `ahk_class` to `MozillaWindowClass`

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Q is disabled now in one of the latest chrome updates, so it is no longer necessary to block

Answer (score 3):

Complete version of this script. Works on new AHK versions.

- Works with any input language (assigned to key code, not key as letter)
- Only one running instance (SingleInstance force)
- Doesn't recording history of pressed keys (KeyHistory 0)
- Prevents from Ctrl+Shift+W and Ctrl+Shift+Q in Chrome

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#SingleInstance force;
#KeyHistory 0 ;
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SetTitleMatchMode, Regex
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    ^+SC011::
        ;do nothing
        return
    ^+SC010::
        ;do nothing
        return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: please help me format this code!

Comment: You had missed the closing `</pre>` tag

Comment: The chrome keybinding is language dependent for at least my version (61.0.3163.100) of chrome, so it doesn't work better to use the scancode.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the Chrome extension ["Disable keyboard shortcuts"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-keyboard-shortcut/aidbmcboeighgdnilpdljbedbbiocphj), by Benjamin Barenblat. (You may also [view the source code](https://github.com/google/disable-keyboard-shortcuts), if you wish.)
2. Visit the URL: `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`
3. If you're on Windows, assign <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to do nothing in Chrome. (If you're on Mac OS, assign <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> instead.)

Answer (score 0):

This binds ctrl-w to perform a kind of select-word in every application, and disables closing chrome using ctrl-shift-w and ctrl-shift-q.  Tested on english and french language input methods for windows 10.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
#SingleInstance FORCE
#KeyHistory 0
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

^w:: ; select word
    Send, ^{right}^{left}^+{right}
    return

SetTitleMatchMode, Regex
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    ^+w::return ; make ctrl-shift-w do nothing
    ^+q::return ; make ctrl-shift-q do nothing
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the autohotkey code to disable ctrl+w and ctrl+q for the tab named test1 and test2 (test1 is the title that appears on your tab. You can use also use autohotkey spy to figure out more stuff)

```
SetTitleMatchMode, Regex

#If WinActive("test1 ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") || WinActive("test2 ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") 
        ^w::
        ^q::
            return  ; do nothing

#IfWinActive
```

credit to [Raj](https://superuser.com/a/782979/235752) and [this guy](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=39492&p=180605#p180605)

Answer (score 0):

it think this might work:

1- Press `WIN + R` to open Run dialog (alternatively right click Start, select Run), type `control /name Microsoft.Language`, press OK:

2- This opens Control Panel > All Control Panel items > Language. Select Advanced settings:

3- Select Change language bar hot keys:

4- In Advanced Key Settings tab, select Change Key Sequence:

5- Change key sequence, click OK to save settings:

6- Notice that Switch Input Language and Switch Keyboard Layout can't have the same sequence. To avoid using `CTRL + SHIFT` you can for instance set Switch Input Language to Grave Accent and Switch Keyboard Layout to Left `Alt + SHIFT`