# Is it possible for a pinned tab in Chrome to be protected?

Tags: google-chrome

Am using Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 beta in Ubuntu 12.04.

I use pinned tabs for various Google apps (Gmail, Calendar, Contacts, Drive). I also use bookmarks bar for frequently visited sites. If my browser's focus is on Gmail, and I click on a bookmark, or type something into the Omnibar, then the new destination loads into the pinned tab. I would like for the pinned tab to remain protected, so that these behaviors would open a new tab by default.

The same behavior happens on Chrome in a Windows environment.

I use pinned tabs in Firefox and it behaves correctly (new URLs are launched in new tabs and tab is protected). Because of issues with Firefox and Google Talk Video acceleration I need to use Chrome right now.

Comment: Typing in the address bar would also change the current page in Firefox. I would assume that can't be locked.

Comment: I don't know about pinned tab but you can disable ctrl+w (or any shortcuts) of specific tabs (using a part of their name) using that https://superuser.com/a/1265878/235752

Answer (score 11):

From reading the feature request [Locking Pinned Tabs](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-discuss/wW-6qyh2YTM), I would assume that this is not possible in Chrome without extensions.

The thread mentions that extensions exist to achieve this. For example, [Lock Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lock-tab/jnikalcnjojfkpleicbncjmnieimjlfe).

After installation of the extension, you'll see a small lock icon in the address bar:

[image]

By clicking it, you'll *lock* the tab. If you then try to navigate away from it, you'll get the following message:

[image]

Additionally, you'll have the option to "freeze" locked pages. This causes any clicked links on a locked tab to be opened in a new tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Oliver, not working properly for me because right now he can't lock Google pages... Good idea.

Comment: @Kendor: I just gave it a try on a Google Calendar tab. It worked perfectly. Remember to refresh the tab after installing the extension for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, but Gmail (the key one) doesn't work the same way... one gets a dialog that says "Sorry, some special pages (Gmail included...) cannot be locked yet...

Comment: @Kendor: Oh, I see that now. Sorry. Let me see if I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: @Kendor: Humm, okay, I guess the extension works by injecting JavaScript into the current page to prevent you from navigating away. That explains why it won't work on certain pages. Sadly I can't find another extension to solve this. So, sorry that this didn't work out :(

Comment: This extension is obsolete and no longer searchable in the webstore. From the author: "The Chrome "Pin Tab" is doing exactly what this extension want do. I think there may no need to continue update this extension. However, if there're critical bugs exist and you still need this extension, please feel free to tell me, I'll try to fix it. Besides that, I may not update this extension from now on..."

Answer (score 0):

[Lock Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lock-tab/nhbdiieigbgalknjplfpgmjnpbnkchnb) (currently `v1.1.0`) appears to work for me on `macOS v12.6.3, Chrome v109.0.5414.119 (arm64)`...

...IF...

you remember to follow these instructions:

> IMPORTANT: after locking, some interaction with the page is required
> for it to work. So you need to, for example, click anywhere on the
> page after locking to actually prevent the tab from being closed. This
> is how Chrome works.

I have asked the author (in a recent review I posted on the extensions review page) to present these instructions in a way required by the installing user to "acknowledge" upon installation.

Answer (score -1):

Just recently I made an extension that automatically protects pinned tabs from accidental closing:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keep-my-pinned-tab/dcebfccimkdnjbkibdmidghomhcodilp

Comment: Does this actually address the scenarios discussed in the question? How does your extension differ from the ones discussed in the other answer?

Comment: This isn't helpful. The question asks about preventing the tab from changing it's URL.

Comment: On top of that the extension doesn't prevent you from closing pinned tabs using Ctrl-W making it effectively useless.